# Upload files via Ajax and api key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, upload

I have below code for post request but 422 error is shown:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://napi.arvancloud.com/vod/2.0/channels/166c3942-4e8d-4ab7-a543-c46e4528bf08/videos',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorization,
        'Accept-Language': "en"
    },
    data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
        alert('Uploaded by jQuery');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://napi.arvancloud.com/vod/2.0/channels/166c3942-4e8d-4ab7-a543-c46e4528bf08/videos',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': authorization,
                        'Accept-Language': "en"
                    },
                    data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('Uploaded by jQuery');
                    }
                    })
                    
            });
        })
```